# Ignoring Local Notification when device is off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, local

I really need help with Local Notification. When my device is active i can tap "ok", and "action" buttons, but when device is turned off, a can only slide to unlock iPhone, but then automaticly app behave like I've tap "action" button. Anybody knows how  can I put there "OK" button, like in system alarm clock.

Comment: The device isn't off. It's locked. Anyway, as far as I know, the system alarms all use sliders too.

Comment: That's the general way of doing it. So stick with it. Why do you even want to change it?

Comment: I just want to add 'cancel' button when the device is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already know this but [the doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) just says that,

*"If the notification is an alert and the user taps the action button (or, if the device is locked, drags open the action slider), the application is launched".*

And, it doesn't talk about any other option to change this behavior. I too tried to change that but I couldn't find a way. I feel that there is no way other than just to stick with that.